# Bacula postgresql catalog backup

Tags: postgresql, bacula

When I run the BackupCatalog job I get the following error

```
04-Mar 21:04 storo-dir JobId 62: shell command: run BeforeJob "/etc/bacula/scripts/make_catalog_backup.pl MyCatalog"
04-Mar 21:04 storo-dir JobId 62: BeforeJob: pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "bacula" failed: FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
04-Mar 21:04 storo-dir JobId 62: Error: Runscript: BeforeJob returned non-zero status=1. ERR=Child exited with code 1
04-Mar 21:04 storo-dir JobId 62: Error: Bacula storo-dir 5.0.3 (04Aug10): 04-Mar-2012 21:04:35
```

Ok, so I looked at the script:

- the first parameter should be the name of the database
- the second the user
- the third the password
- the fourth the address of the database

but if I run the script in bacula with all the parameters. I get:

```
04-Mar 21:23 storo-dir JobId 63: BeforeJob: Can't find your catalog (bacula) in director configuration
```

Can some one help me and tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's wrong: the first name is the name of the catalog (MyCatalog, according to the output of the first database); so, I guess you're running the script with something like:

```
/etc/bacula/scripts/make_catalog_backup.pl db_name user password host
```

but what you should actually do is:

```
/etc/bacula/scripts/make_catalog_backup.pl MyCatalog db_name user password host
```